# How to use Amazon Route 53 to link to my Weebly Site

Tags: amazon-route53, weebly

I have a website at amazon S3. I registered my domain (Not With Amazon) and pointed it to Route 53 and linked it to my Amazon S3 bucket. Now I want to move my site to Weebly.

I am a teacher and don't know much about this stuff. I watched online tutorials and read articles about linking a domain name using Route 53 to Amazon S3 Bucket and I successfully did.

Now I want to move from Amazon S3 to Weebly and they want me to link to their IP Address  199.34.228.59.  for both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com

Currently I have 2 hosted zones for my domain at Route 53.

one for mydomain.com and one for www.mydomain.com

In "mydomain.com" 
 Type is A-Ipv4Address,
 Alias is Yes and
 alias Target is Amazon Bucket end point.
 Routing Policy is simple

Please forgive me for not being able to explain clearly to you guys.

Just need someone to help me link my domain name to weebly using Amazon Route 53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Alias to "No" for both `www.mydomain.com` and `domain.com`. Keep them as A records, and for both of them just change their values to 199.34.228.59.  That should be all that's necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is one more thing if you could help me with. Before transferring both www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com from Amazon s3 bucket to weebly  I would see  just  mydomain.com in the web address bar. After moving to weebly I see www before my domain and I want  to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about weebly.  That might be a good new question to ask, tagging it as just a weebly question.

Comment: Could you tell me if I need to make 2 hosted zones in Route 53 or just one. currently I have 2 hosted zones one for mydomain.com and one for www.mydomain.com   but in mydomain.com  hosted zone there is an entry of www.mydomain.com